# Daemon- running tasks at certain times

Tags: php, daemon

I've created a PHP daemon that runs.. and its main concern is polling FTP servers at a set interval.

Now, there is now a need to add the same functionality, but at set times as well (so say 7PM on Monday).

How would I modify the service to perform tasks at certain times of the day?

I know I could do something like `IF date() == date task should run then ...`, but if one of the loops takes longer than normal, it might miss running the task.

Any ideas of how to achieve this?

Comment: What about a fork process that perform the task at certain time?

Comment: Is CRON not an option here?

Comment: I'd rather keep it in the 1 daemon as the times are going to be stored in the database. I could create a cron sript that runs every 15 minutes, that checks the DB for jobs for that time I suppose

Comment: What if I have a "Next run" time in the database, and the process checks to see if there are any tasks that are smaller than the current time, but unprocessed? It can then update that time when it processes it so the next run will pick it up. Is this a bit of a clumsy way?